# Import gzipped data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gzip, import-from-csv

I am trying to fetch a gzip from a URL and import it automatically into a Google Sheets. The gzip contains one file of CSV data.

I know I can import the CSV data into a Google Sheets but I would like to be able to cut out the step of me having to download the gzip and extract the file first before uploading it into a Google Sheets.

So my queries:

Is it possible to import a gzipped CSV file from a URL directly into a Google Sheets?

If not, how would this be done with a Google Apps Script?

Comment: It's reported on the issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=964

Comment: thanks for the info Eduardo, I didn't catch this one ;-) so I guess my suggestion won't give any result ... too bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undocumented utility in GAS called unzip, I know it can unzip ordinary .zip files but have no idea if GNU zip are supported... maybe it's worth give it a try ?
here is a quick test I wrote for a zip that was in my google documents/drive

```
function testzip(){
var files=DocsList.getRootFolder().find('Sans titre.txt.zip');
var zipblob=files[0].getBlob();
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();// it is a text file
DocsList.createFile('Sans titre.txt',unzipstr);// I kept the original name to make it simple
}
```

Don't blame me if it doesn't work for you... it's just a proposal ;-)

Comment: Thank-you Serge!

I tried this with my gzip file but sadly it did not work as Eduardo thought it might not.  Luckily I have the option of downloading my data as a zip or gzip, so your script helped me a great deal.  I simply needed to use UrlFetchApp to fetch my zip and run it through the code you suggested.  Thanks again.

Comment: my pleasure ;-) If you don't mind to publish your complete code I guess it could be useful to show it here doesn't it ?

Comment: As requested by Serge, here is my final code to download a zip file containing one csv file from a url. The unzipped file is held in the variable unzipstr as a string.

`
    function testzip(){  
      var url = "myurlhere"  
      var zipblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();  
      var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);  
      var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();  
      Logger.log(unzipstr);  
    }  
`
I hope it helps someone, thank-you for everyone that helped me on this!  I give up trying to get this to display right!

Comment: Hey, did you find any sollution? I am solving the same problem. I have URL with xml.gz file which is generated every day by third party service and I need to push it into Google Spreadsheet. Any solution please?

Comment: what exactly are you trying ? update the above code with driveApp instead of DocList and it should work

Comment: or else ask a new question

Answer (score 5):

I was able to inflate (decompress) a gzipped file using a third party javascript library, pako. Here is the code:

```
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js').getContentText());

  var charData = UrlFetchApp.fetch("<url to a .gz file>").getContent();

  var binData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < charData.length; i++) {
    binData.push(charData[i] < 0 ? charData[i] + 256 : charData[i]);
  }

  var data = pako.inflate(binData);

  var decoded = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    decoded += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  }
```