# Script to unzip attachment

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to create a Google Apps Script, that takes attachment of e-mails, unzips it a forwards it. I saw unpacking feature in Google Drive (you can upload a file there, open it and copy individual files to you drive). Is this functionality accessible from Google Apps Script somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to write a script for automatically makes attachments of an email as directly uploaded on user's Google Drive after this trigger run this piece of code shown below

```
function testzip(){
var files=DocsList.getRootFolder().find('Sans titre.txt.zip');
var zipblob=files[0].getBlob();
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
var unzipstr=unzipblob[0].getDataAsString();// it is a text file
DocsList.createFile('Sans titre.txt',unzipstr);// I kept the original name to make it simple
}
```

Check this code. Don't blame me if it won't work. It's just a proposal.

Comment: Nice, works on Blobs directly, without the detour to Drive. Thanks

Comment: Where did you find the `Utilities.unzip`, I was not able to find anything about it in the reference, is there a better resource for the API?

Comment: @puco check here utilities class for google apps scripts https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities

Comment: The code here appears to be drawn from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089910/import-gzipped-data-into-google-spreadsheet/11091720#11091720

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Files *are* blobs so need to call getBlob(). Anything that has a getBlob() function can be used as a blob directly. You can replace

```
var zipblob=files[0].getBlob();
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipblob);
```

with this:

```
var zipfile=files[0];
var unzipblob = Utilities.unzip(zipfile);
```

I tried to edit the other answer, but someone who apparently didn't try the code rejected the edit as incorrect.